# How to discriminate on multiple properties in an OpenAPI schema?

Tags: openapi

[Here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism) the documentation explains how to define discriminators when an OpenAPI schema is dependent on the value of a property. In my own project, I have a schema that is dependent on the values of **two properties**, not just one. I wonder whether there is any way to model that in an OpenAPI file?

Let's say we have a list of requests with two required enum properties:

- requestType: It could be either of these values:

  - New
  - Old
- periodType: It could be either of these values:

  - Temporary
  - Permanent

The values of the rest of properties are somehow dependent on the values of these 2 fields. So there are 4 possible schemas which we want to discriminate them based on these 2 fields. One possible solution that came to my mind was to use a nested structure like this:

```yaml
ListResponse: 
      type: array
      items:
        oneOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
        discriminator:
          propertyName: requestType
          mapping:
            'New':
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
              discriminator:
                propertyName: periodType
                mapping:
                  'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
                  'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
            'Old':
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
              discriminator:
                propertyName: periodType
                mapping:
                  'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
                  'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
      uniqueItems: true
```

But seemingly this is not a valid schema. So, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use these keywords to create a complex schema, or validate a
> value against multiple criteria

I am unsure if the below can generate a correct validation, however, your YAML open api should use [`oneOf` (or `allOf`)](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) within schema definitions:

```yaml
ListResponse: 
  type: array
  uniqueItems: true
  items:
    oneOf:
      - oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
        discriminator:
          propertyName: periodType
          mapping:
            'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
            'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
      - oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
        discriminator:
          propertyName: periodType
          mapping:
            'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
            'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
    discriminator:
      propertyName: requestType
      mapping:
        'New': '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
        'Old': '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
```

The referred `propertyName` in [the discriminator](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/) (i.e. `periodType`) MUST be present in the child schemas as well as `required`.

> It is important that all the models mentioned below `anyOf` or `oneOf` contain the property that the discriminator specifies.

```yaml
NewTemporaryRequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - periodType
  properties:
    periodType:
      type: string
      enum: [Temporary, Permanent]
NewPermantentRequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - periodType
  # etc
OldTemporaryRequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - periodType
  # etc
OldPermanentRequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - periodType
  # etc
```

If after reviewing the above this still does not work, maybe the below disambiguates the validation:

```yaml
ListResponse: 
  type: array
  uniqueItems: true
  items:
    oneOf:
      - allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
        - oneOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
          discriminator:
            propertyName: periodType
            mapping:
              'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
              'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
      - allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
        - oneOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
          discriminator:
            propertyName: periodType
            mapping:
              'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
              'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
    discriminator:
      propertyName: requestType
      mapping:
        'New': '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
        'Old': '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
```

The above, though, also requires the parent schema models to have the discriminator of the level they appear explicitly defined as property and required:

```yaml
NewRequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - requestType
    - periodType
  properties:
    requestType:
      type: string
      enum: [New, Old]
    periodType:
      type: string
      enum: [Temporary, Permanent]
  # etc
OldRequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - requestType
    - periodType
  properties:
    requestType:
      type: string
      enum: [New, Old]
    periodType:
      type: string
      enum: [Temporary, Permanent]
  # etc
```

#### Avoiding Redundant Definitions

It's not clear at which extent parent-child inference on properties is supported on each of the Open API released versions. When using [inheritance and polymorphism](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/), you should technically be able to avoid repeating definitions/properties (i.e. defining `periodType` in the parent schemas would then suffice, rather than defining it also in the child models as well).

In the [Open API `3.1.0`](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#discriminator-object) there are some recommendations to avoid redundancy:

> In both the `oneOf` and `anyOf` use cases, all possible schemas MUST be
> listed explicitly. To avoid redundancy, the **discriminator MAY be added
> to a parent schema definition**, and all schemas comprising the parent
> schema in an `allOf` construct may be used as an **alternate schema**.
> In scenarios where the value of the discriminator field does not match the schema name or implicit mapping is not possible, an optional mapping definition MAY be used.

1. So technically, you should be able to define the `discriminator`
   right in the parent model itself, and define the `mappings` as well
   in there.
2. The text also says that you are only required to define the mappings
   for values of the property that do not exactly match (case
   sensitive) the name of the schema model they map to (because the
   rest will automatically map).

It must be said that the 1st point above is somehow confusing, because some lines above the document it also says:

> The discriminator object is legal only when using one of the composite keywords oneOf, anyOf, allOf.
> When using the discriminator, inline schemas will not be considered.

However, according their pets example (further down in the docs), the discriminator will actually be considered when the model is referenced (`$ref`) as part of an `allOf` statement in its children models. Although this point is not explicitly stated in the descriptions, it makes the entire chain of definitions far simpler.

So following your example, technically the below should be possible, at least in Open `API 3.1.0` (I am also unsure if it would work in previous versions):

(**not tested**)

```yaml
RequestType:
  type: string
  enum: [New, Old]
PeriodType:
  type: string
  enum: [Temporary, Permanent]
RequestResponse:
  type: object
  required:
    - requestType
  properties:
    requestType:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestType'
  discriminator:
    propertyName: requestType
    mapping:
      'New': '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
      'Old': '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
NewRequestResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestResponse'
    - type: object
      required:
        - periodType
      properties:
        periodType:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/PeriodType'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: periodType
        mapping:
          'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/NewTemporaryRequestResponse'
          'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/NewPermanentRequestResponse'
OldRequestResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestResponse'
    - type: object
      required:
        - periodType
      properties:
        periodType:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/PeriodType'
      discriminator:
        propertyName: periodType
        mapping:
          'Temporary': '#/components/schemas/OldTemporaryRequestResponse'
          'Permanent': '#/components/schemas/OldPermanentRequestResponse'
NewTemporaryRequestResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
    - type: object
      properties:
        # all properties specific to this schema
NewPermantentRequestResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewRequestResponse'
    - type: object
      properties:
        # all properties specific to this schema
OldTemporaryRequestResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
    - type: object
      properties:
        # all properties specific to this schema
OldPermanentRequestResponse:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OldRequestResponse'
    - type: object
      properties:
        # all properties specific to this schema
```

Then, in your original List response, you would just do:

```yaml
ListResponse: 
  type: array
  uniqueItems: true
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestResponse'
```

As a final note, when update and get models have differences, you can keep a unique model definition by specifying the `readOnly` (only retrieval or in responses) and the `writeOnly` (only when updating or in request payloads) boolean flags of those specific properties that are unique to updates or unique to retrievals (rather than defining the update submodels separately).